# LINQ - Find certain Item in the List<T> By Count criteria

Tags: c#, linq

**I have an `EmployeeSchedule` Class**

```
public class EmployeeSchedule
{
    public string EmpId { get; set; }
    public string Shift { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek Day{ get; set; }
}
```

**With this implementation:**

```
List<EmployeeSchedule> ess = new List<EmployeeSchedule>
{
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1001", Shift = "OFF", Day = Sunday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1001", Shift = "MOR", Day = Monday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1001", Shift = "MOR", Day = Tuesday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1001", Shift = "MOR", Day = Wednesday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1001", Shift = "MOR", Day = Thursday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1001", Shift = "MOR", Day = Friday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1001", Shift = "MOR", Day = Saturday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1002", Shift = "SWN", Day = Sunday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1003", Shift = "GY", Day = Sunday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1004", Shift = "GY", Day = Sunday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1005", Shift = "MOR", Day = Sunday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1005", Shift = "MOR", Day = Monday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1005", Shift = "MOR", Day = Tuesday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1005", Shift = "MOR", Day = Wednesday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1005", Shift = "MOR", Day = Thursday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1006", Shift = "SWN", Day = Sunday },
    new EmployeeSchedule { EmpId = "1007", Shift = "MOR", Day = Sunday }
}
```

**I want to get certain item in the list with its `COUNT` criteria:**

1. Where `SHIFT "MOR"` count is less than 2: this will get me `EmpId = "1007"`
2. Where `SHIFT "MOR"` count is equal to 5: this will get me `EmpId = "1005"`

So far i tried this but i don't really have any idea where or how to put the `COUNT` as criteria.

```
var id = ess.Where(x => x.Shift == "MOR").FirstOrDefault();
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: A simple `Where()` method but it doesnt seems to work, since i have no idea where to put the `COUNT` as criteria.

Comment: As a side note: `EmpId` is defined as an integer but you're passing a string.

Comment: o yeah thank you for correction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Where` and `GroupBy` + `Count`:

```
var empIdGroupsWithMorShift = ess
    .Where(es => es.Shift == "MOR")
    .GroupBy(es => es.EmpId);
var lessTwo = empIdGroupsWithMorShift
    .Where(g => g.Count() < 2)
    .Select(g => new  { EmpId = g.Key, Count = g.Count()} );
var five = empIdGroupsWithMorShift
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 5)
    .Select(g => new { EmpId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

If you only want a string as result as commented you can use `String.Join`:

```
string five = String.Join(",", empIdGroupsWithMorShift
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 5)
    .Select(g => g.Key));  // "1005"
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem thanks!, but it is possible if the object result is already a string? so when i access the result i wont need to use foreach. Thanks already!

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab: sure, for example, if you want to store only the `EmpIds` of the employees which count is 5 and separate them with comma: `string fiveResult = String.Join(",", five.Select(x => x.EmpId))`

Comment: Just use `.Select(g => g.Key)` instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the criteria will always yield one result so i would like to be a direct string for example `fiVe` would be equals to direct string as `1005` and lessTwo as `1007`

@ArthurRey i tried to replace it with `g.Key` but it doesnt seems to work either.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab: have you seen that i've updated my answer? The `String.Join` handles the case that there are multiple results, but if there's only one it works too(no comma appended).

Answer (score 3):

You can try using *Linq*:

```
  var result2 = ess
   .GroupBy(record => record.EmpId)
   .Where(chunk => chunk.Count(record => record.Shift == "MOR") < 2)
   .Select(chunk => chunk.Key);

  var result5 = ess
    .GroupBy(record => record.EmpId)
    .Where(chunk => chunk.Count(record => record.Shift == "MOR") == 5)
    .Select(chunk => chunk.Key);

  // Test
  // 1005
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result5));
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Tim Schmelter's answer, you could create an extension method to make it easier to filter your data

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string[] GetByShiftCount(this List<EmployeeSchedule> list, string shift, Func<int, bool> filter)
    {
        return list.Where(x => x.Shift == shift)
                   .GroupBy(x => x.EmpId)
                   .Where(g => filter(g.Count()))
                   .Select(g => g.Key)
                   .ToArray();
    }
}
```

That you can use it like so

```
string[] EmpIds = ess.GetByShiftCount("MOR", x => x < 2);
string[] EmpIds = ess.GetByShiftCount("MOR", x => x == 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

for getting list you have to call `ToList();`
 you can get count like this

```
var mylist = ess.Where(c=>c.Shift =="MOR").ToList();

if(mylist.count > 5
```

//logic goes here

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would be the solution (Updated):

```
var sorted = ess.Where(w => w.Shift == "MOR").GroupBy(g=>g.EmpId);
var result1 = sorted.Where(g1 => g1.Count() < 2);
var result2 = sorted.Where(g2 => g2.Count() == 2);
```

Comment: Yes, It's current context :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 var result = ess.GroupBy(x => x.EmpId).Where(x => x.Count() < 2).SelectMany(x => x).Where(x => x.Shift == "MOR");
```